# How can i change order of antd prop So my row selection and expand row order change

Tags: next.js, antd

```
 <Table
            dataSource={dataSource}
            pagination={false}
            rowKey={(record) => record.id}
            rowSelection={rowSelection}
            expandable={{
              expandedRowRender,
              expandIcon: customExpandIcon,
            }}
          >
```

how can i add prop or state so it will work properly

I tried prop order but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Table.SELECTION_COLUMN` and `TABLE.EXPAND_COLUMN` to change the position in columns list.
Here's the complete code which render selection column first and then expandable column or you can follow antd [Order Specific Column](https://ant.design/components/table#components-table-demo-order-column) example.

```
import { Table } from 'antd';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Table
            rowSelection={{}}
            expandable={{ expandedRowRender: (record) => <p>{record.address}</p> }}
            dataSource={[
                { key: '1', name: 'Mike', age: 32, address: '10 Downing Street' },
                { key: '2', name: 'John', age: 42, address: '10 Downing Street' }
            ]}
            columns={[
                Table.SELECTION_COLUMN,
                Table.EXPAND_COLUMN,
                { title: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', key: 'name' },
                { title: 'Age', dataIndex: 'age', key: 'age' },
                { title: 'Address', dataIndex: 'address', key: 'address' }
            ]}
        />
    );
};

export default App;
```